# Not getting proper output from regex in mongodb.find() function

Tags: python, mysql, regex, mongodb

I have a function called isNearestDataExist. I want it to return query result like mysql 'LIKE' operator. Where it can send response if only one word is there in the sentence. Example
input: 'what is your name?', 'name?', 'your name' etc
output: 'Some name'

SELECT answer FROM tbl_chats WHERE asked_column IS LIKE '%input%';
This query is returning proper response from mysql. But in mongoDB its only giving response when the whole exact sentence is given as an input. I tried with many techniques but i couldn't get the proper response like mysql. Kindly help me. Sorry for my poor English. Thanks in advance.

```
def isNearestDataExist(self, col_name, key, value):
    col_name = 'col_chats'
    key = 'asked'
    value = 'what is your name?'
    result = Mongo.db[col_name].find( {key: {"$regex": '/'+value+'/'}})
    return result
```

Comment: Try this , ```result = Mongo.db[col_name].find( {key: {"$regex": '.*'+value+'.*'}})```

Comment: Sir you just saved my day @Sushanth Thank you so much sir. It worked like a charm.

Comment: Are you sure you need `.*` at all? Use `{"$regex": value}` or - since `value` may contain special chars, ``{"$regex": re.escape(value)}``. If `.*` are required to return full string, use ```{"$regex": ".*" + re.escape(value) + ".*"}```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
def isNearestDataExist(self, col_name, key, value):
    col_name = 'col_chats'
    key = 'asked'
    #value = 'what is your name?'
    regx = re.compile(value, re.IGNORECASE)
    result = Mongo.db[col_name].find( {key: regx})
    return result
```